# I installed eclipse and did some work on it but when I tried to start eclipse again . I got this error

Tags: eclipse

[This pop up is opening when i tried to run eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwSFm.png)

Whenever I installed eclipse it run perfectly first time but when I start again after some time, this error comes up. This directory is not created in my .eclipe too.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear and also tells what to do. So what is your question? If you think the error message is displayed by mistake, you are wrong. It is for real that the user with which you run Eclipse has no permissions to create that directory (or access it if it already exists). It is unclear what you have installed and how (`org.eclipse.platform_4.20.0_1086-49632_win32_win32_x86_64`:do you really want to install only the Eclipse Platform and not the Eclipse Java IDE?; _.eclipe_ is a typo, right?).

Comment: @howlger Yes, I should have written Eclipse java IDE. Actually What I want to ask is what should I do so that user get permit.

Comment: What did you download (please provide a link) and how did you install it (there more one way)? If you use the Eclipse Installer, do not run it _As Administrator_ and make sure you have chosen a Java IDE, not the Platform.

Comment: @howlger Thanks running it as administrator did work. It was stupid of me to not think this .